# Re-ordering an object by an integer value

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have a large object that I need to sort by a value, so that is is listed in descending order (the range is `7-2`). At the moment, I'm not sure what is really handling the sorting order, it seems fairly random to me though I assume there is some logic.

Here is an example subset of the data:

```
property_list = {
   1 : {
       description : '...',
       specs : {
          bedroom_number: 7
       }
   },
   2 : {
      description : '...',
      specs : {
         bedroom_number: 3
      }
   },
   3 : {
      description : '...',
      specs : {
          bedroom_number: 5
      }
   }
}
```

So I need to reorder by `specs.bedroom_number` so that they are arrange as `7`, `5`, `3` in terms of the bedroom number value.

Is this sort of sorting possible? Or does it require some sort of loop to work through the object and add each object to a new set of data?

Comment: Objects don't have an order. You can sort the *keys* of an object in an array use that or you can store your data in an array instead of an object.

Comment: @MikeC So this is only possible with an array? How is the ordering done with an array?

Comment: If you have them in an array, you can use the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. Pass it your own sorting function so you compare the `spec.bedroom_number` values. The link I posted shows an example of how to write your own sorting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array  of objects out of your variable `property_list` and then sort by `specs.bedroom_number` with the use of [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var property_list = {1: {description: '...',specs: {bedroom_number: 7}},2: {description: '...',specs: {bedroom_number: 3}},3: {description: '...',specs: {bedroom_number: 5}}},
    arr = Object
        .keys(property_list)
        .map(function (key) {
            return property_list[key];
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.specs.bedroom_number - a.specs.bedroom_number;
        });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: So glad to help